# Makefile.win (28): fatal error U1050: PGROOT is not set Stop

Tags: postgresql, windows, pgvector

I am working on lanchain and had to store data in vector DB. I was following [this document](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#installation-notes) to install pgvector on windows and i was setting the PGROOT env variable, but even after setting the env variable by multiple methods the CMD `nmake /F Makefile.win install` keep throwing the error
**Makefile.win (28): fatal error U1050: PGROOT is not set Stop.**

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I did that worked for me.

I located `!ifndef PGROOT` in the **Makefile.win** file in the PGVector folder that I cloned from the git ([Link](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector)) to be installed and set the variable explicitly like for example: `PGROOT = C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16` (my pg version was 16), before the `!ifndef PGROOT` line.
This is a workaround if you are not able to set the env variable in Windows.
I tried setting, `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($envVariableName, $envVariableValue, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)` as well.